# Email link not working on mobile site wrapped by an Android app.

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile

Working on a mobile website wrapped in an Android app. The contact us page has email link

`<a href="mailto:support@abc.com" class="contact-button ui-corner-all"><img src="/img/contact_email_icon.png" width="25"/>Email: support@abc.com</a>`

It works on webpage if opened in browser but not in app. I want it to prompt user to use email app in order to send the email. Please help.

Comment: Add `target="_blank"` to the link.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to remove the double "" from the email link the image tag and the class tag. If you want an image link you have to implement it using android ImageView layout, not an HTML tag.

```
TextView email = findViewById(R.id.email);
    String emailText = "<a href='mailto:support@abc.com'>support@abc.com</a>";
    email.setText(Html.fromHtml(emailText));
    email.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```